# Custom List of all items in Webform

Tags: webforms

After 10 webforms have been added. How could we creat a HTML report to list all items inside drupal ?

Comment: Can you clarify? What items do you want to list? Do you want to list webform submissions from all 10 forms?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it sounds like you need to create a view to output submissions.

Webform helps you here by integrating fully with views so you can pull out whatever data you need. You can also create a view per webform which will enable you to have a separate page for each.

Failing that, if you go to Content Management > Webforms it gives you a summary of all webforms on the site with links to view submissions, export them, etc.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the [Site Documentation](http://drupal.org/project/sitedoc) module is close to what you are looking for.